# Example / Counterexample of non constant analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

While trying assignments of complex analysis I am unable to solve this particular question.

> Does there exists a non-constant bounded analytic function on $\mathbb{C} $/{0} ?

As function  is not entire so lioville theorem can't  be applied . So I think there might exist a function but I am unable to find any.

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you mean set exclusion? Then first apply Riemann’s extension theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. Any such function $f$ would be bounded near $0$. So, by Riemann's extension theorem, $f$ can be extended to an analytical function $\hat{f}$ in $\Bbb{C}$. But $\hat{f}$ is bounded and entire, so it is constant. Since $f=\hat{f}$ in $\Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, $f$ is constant too.

Comment: Augusto can you please tell where can I study Riemann extension theorem ?  It is not part of our course.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem